# Relacionando chaves e valores de um dicionário Python

Tags: python, funções, lista, dicionário

Boa noite, galera. Bom, sou um programador iniciante em python e me deparei com uma questão de dicionários que não consigo compreender como resolvê-la.

Basicamente, ele pede para relacionar um dicionário do tipo

```
dicionario = {'A': ['B', 'C', 'D',],
'B': ['A'],
'C': ['E', 'F', 'G'],
'D':['B'], 
'E': ['A','B'], 
'F': ['A', 'B', 'C']}
```

E caso tenhamos uma identidade do tipo

```
A contém B e B contém A
```

Tem de se retornar uma lista com uma tupla que demonstre essa identidade

```
[(A, B), (C, F)]
```

Até o momento, tenho o seguinte código (que imagino estar muito errado pois ainda não entendi a lógica):

```
def deu_match(dicionario):

 newlist = []
 lista = dicionario.items()
 valores = dicionario.values()
 chaves = dicionario.keys()
 for i in range(len(lista)):
    if list(lista)[i][0][0] in valores:
        for chave in chaves:
           if valores[chave] == dicionario[chave]:
              newlist = newlist.append([lista[i][0][0], chave])

 return newlist
```

Que está resultando em uma lista completamente vazia.

Podem me ajudar? Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 0):

uma das maneiras de  fazer essa validação seria por brute force ou seja
interar entre todas as combinações do seu objeto

no exemplo que eu montei ao invés de eu varrer a estrutura como dicionário,
eu pré transformei elas em pares de tupla assim eu só preciso verificar a primeira e a segunda posição de cada item na lista de combinações.

```py
def deu_match(dicionario):
  
  pairs =[]
  for key,value in dicionario.items():
    #Converto em pares de tuplas  : (A,B)
    for v in value:
      p = (key,v)
      pairs.append(p)

  result = []
  for i in range(len(pairs)):
    x = pairs[i]
    for j in range(i+1,len(pairs)):
      y= pairs[j]

      # Verifico se existe algum par parecido
      # a posição em que a letra se encontra é desconsiderado então é considerado (A,B) ou (B,A) como corretos neste exemplo
      if x == y or (x[0] == y[1] and x[1] == y[0]):
        if x not in result and (x[1],x[0]) not in result:
            result.append(x)
    
  return set(result)

# >> OUTPUT
# {('A', 'B'), ('C', 'F')}
```